# Qt: Setting TableView Highlight color in Linux

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, pyqt, pyqt4

I’m using PyQt4/PySide, but this problem occurs in both, so I think it’s a Qt problem generally. I have a TableView. When I want to set the background color of highlighted table items in Windows, I can get the TableView’s palette and call

```
palette.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, QColor(someColor))
```

and that sets the background color of a highlighted item, no problem. However, this does not work in Linux. (Specifically the different versions of Ubuntu that I’ve tried.) Instead the highlighted color is always an orange color that Ubuntu likes to use. Is there a way to fix this? Setting other types of colors, such as QPalette.Text, works fine, it’s a QPalette.Highlight issue only.

Comment: You are not using stylesheets? Have you tried `setStyleSheet("QTableView{ border: none; background: myColor }");`? or `myView.setFrameStyle(Qt::NoFrame);`?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7840590/984421).

Comment: @lpapp unfortunately neither of these helps change the background color of highlighted items.

Comment: @ekhumoro this seems to work for QTableWidget, but not QTableView, strangely (and it's not because I forgot to change use of the class name).

Comment: @wdep1. Okay, that's some progress, I suppose. Could you post a minimal, runnable example that shows the problem on your target system(s), so that others can see if they can reproduce it?